# Updating existing credit cards on paypal with Java REST api

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I am trying to use paypal REST java api to make payments and other related operations in my application. The application is still in development mode (not live). So we are going with the paypal sandbox account.

I am able to do all operations with java REST api, other than updating an already registered card with paypal.

I don't see a method that accepts patch (as it is there for updating payment)

When I use the creditcard.upddate(authtoken) method, it always throws an exception that complains about MALFORMED_REQUEST.

Is the update feature implemented with credit cards, in java? (I am not seeing any examples anywhere)

If so how to do it? What am I missing?

I am using the rest-api-sdk 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the REST API document here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#update-a-stored-credit-card

This document does not directly explain how exactly the SDK works, but will give you some info so that you can check the request parameters.

Comment: I have a CreditCard object, say creditCardObj. I update the fields which are to be updated and then I call

creditCardObj.update(accessToken); This is the only option available with java api.

But when the update method is called, it throws the exception:

com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 400 with response : {"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API ...}

Am I doing something wrong?

creditCardObj.update(accessToken) => is this method supposed to work?

Comment: According to the doc, it says "PATCH /v1/vault/credit-cards/<Credit-Card-Id>". So I think the SDK you are using might be expecting a credit card obj or at least a credit card ID, not the accessToken. If I remember it right (I don't use REST a lot), the accessToken is used during auth process, and it's not the actual data.